# Failed to map guest I/O buffer for write access with status 0xC0000044 Hyper-V-StorageVSP Event ID 8

Tags: windows-server-2019, failovercluster, vhdx, cluster-shared-volumes

Full Error information:
Error   8/9/2021 10:35:11 AM    Hyper-V-StorageVSP  8   None

Failed to map guest I/O buffer for write access with status 0xC0000044. Device name = d:\vms\servername\virtual hard disks\servername.vhdx

This error is switching between different vhdx files on the same Cluster Shared Volume. Some days it reports on servername1.vhdx others on servername2.vhdx
[image]

I recently updated all firmware and drivers on this server HP DL360 Gen 10, Broadcom NX1 i311 network adapters. No change still reports these errors from time to time for a day or so. Also running Shadow Protect as backups service.

I'm not experiencing negative impact from these events and it looks like others have run into them as well without resolution from MS support:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/267595/windows-10-vms-generating-storage-errors-on-2019-h.html

I'll update as I learn more.

Comment: thats not the complete details of the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved when we did two things
(Wish I had done them on different dates to know which on solved the issue.)

1. Removed Cylance antivirus from the environment.
2. Powered down the core aruba switch the SAN and Servers connect to. All other components had been power cycled before and the issue persisted.